# Referencing self in a long-running Rust thread

Tags: rust

I'm left scratching my head about how to design this. Basically, I want to implement a worker pool – kind of similar to the `ThreadPool` from [the book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch20-02-multithreaded.html), but with a twist. In the book, they just pass a closure for one of the threads in the pool to run. However, I would like to have some state for every thread in the pool. Let me explain:

```rust
use std::sync::{mpsc, Arc, Mutex};
use std::thread;

struct Job {
    x: usize,
}

struct WorkerPool {
    sender: mpsc::Sender<Job>,
    workers: Vec<Worker>,
}

impl WorkerPool {
    fn new(num_workers: usize) -> WorkerPool {
        let mut workers = Vec::with_capacity(num_workers);
        let (sender, receiver) = mpsc::channel();
        let receiver = Arc::new(Mutex::new(receiver));

        for id in 0..num_workers {
            workers.push(Worker::new(id, receiver.clone()));
        }

        WorkerPool { sender, workers }
    }
}

struct Worker {
    id: usize,
    thread: Option<thread::JoinHandle<()>>,
    receiver: Arc<Mutex<mpsc::Receiver<Job>>>,
}

impl Worker {
    fn new(id: usize, receiver: Arc<Mutex<mpsc::Receiver<Job>>>) -> Worker {
        Worker {
            id,
            thread: None,
            receiver,
        }
    }

    fn start(&mut self) {
        self.thread = Some(thread::spawn(move || loop {
            let job = self.receiver.lock().unwrap().recv().unwrap();
            self.add_to_id(job.x);
        }));
    }

    pub fn add_to_id(&self, x: usize) {
        println!("The result is: {}", self.id + x);
    }
}
```

Every one of my `Worker`s gets an id, and its job is to accept a `Job` containing a number, and printing its id plus that number (this is, of course, a simplified version; in my real use case, each worker gets an HTTP client and some other state). Pretty simple problem in my eyes, but obviously the code above does not compile.

I realize that the code in `Worker::start` cannot possibly work, because it is moving `self` into the thread closure while I am trying to assign to `self` at the same time.

The question is, how else would I access the fields in the "parent" struct of the thread?

Can I somehow constrain the thread closures lifetime to that of the struct? (Pretty sure the answer is no, because closures have to be `'static`). Or the other way around, do I have to make everything `'static` here?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure the exact problem you are trying to solve. But you can make your code compile by ensuring that references accessed within thread remain valid throughout the lifetime of thread. Make `id` remain valid using `Arc<Mutex<usize>>`

Shows an example where you make your code compile:
https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ed750f5ba5db9597efb9b2b80bde2959

```
    let recv = self.receiver.clone();
    let id = self.id.clone();
    self.thread = Some(thread::spawn(move || loop {
        let job = recv.lock().unwrap().recv().unwrap();
        //self.add_to_id(job.x);
        *id.lock().unwrap() = job.x;
    }));
```